# Determine if 2 users already have a private chat

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database schema for a simple chat app (simplified):

```
## users table
id

## chats table
id, type

## chat_user
chat_id, user_id
```

The issue I want to solve is that given I have 2 users, how can I get a `chat` record for a given `type` given I know that this specific chat `type` should only exist once if it already exists?

For example, we have **bob (id: 1)** and **james (id: 2)**. **bob** initiates a chat with **james**:

```
insert into chats (type) values ('private') returning id;
-- returned ID is: 1234

insert into chat_user (chat_id, user_id) values (1234, 1);
insert into chat_user (chat_id, user_id) values (1234, 2);
```

Now I want a query that will yield the `chat` row with the ID `1234` if I give it the 2 users.

one solution I found for that is finding the intersecting `chat_id` for those 2 users and since I know that there is only ever 1 `private` chat for those 2 users, I simply take the first result:

```sql
select * from chats where id in (
  select chat_id from chat_user where user_id = 1 and chat_id in (
    select chat_id from chat_user where user_id = 2
  )
) and type = 'private' limit 1;
```

Now, while this works, I wonder if this is the best solution for this? Will this query get slower and slower as users have more chats?

If it matters, I'm using **Postgres** for this chat app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`INTERSECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html):

```
select * from chats 
where type = 'private'
and id in (
  select chat_id from chat_user where user_id = 1 
  intersect
  select chat_id from chat_user where user_id = 2
)
limit 1;
```

I don't think that LIMIT 1 is needed if there can only be at most 1 result returned.
Or join the tables, filter, group by id and set a condition in the `having` clause:

```
select c.id 
from chats c inner join chat_user u
on u.chat_id = c.id
where c.type = 'private' and u.user_id in (1, 2) 
group by c.id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any difference between our solutions? The code in my question does an implicit intersect while yours does an explicit one. Does the query planner can use this special postgres syntax and run the query faster than my aforementioned solution?

Comment: @kfirba: you can always check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: I can't tell without your actual tables. You can check with `EXPLAIN`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, forpas,  I'm not entirely sure which plan is better. Is there any way I can post the 2 execution plans here? Perhaps a pastebin?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Implicit Intersection (query in the question): https://explain.depesz.com/s/TjNT. Explicit Intersection https://explain.depesz.com/s/TWRx. Join solution: https://explain.depesz.com/s/ozvi. Looks like the `join` solution is the fastest? I still wonder which one of the implicit/explicit intersection is faster

Comment: @kfirba: `INTERSECT` was the first to come to my mind, too. It's very readable, which I value a lot. That query would benefit from this index: `create index idx on chat_user (user_id, chat_user);` Maybe you have this index already, if your primary key is defined by the two columns in that order.

Comment: @kfirba it seems that my 2nd query performs better, but are your tables sufficiently populated? If yes, then go with that.

Comment: @forpas the tables have few rows in it, actually. I ran an `explain` query and not `explain analyze`. Does it matter?

Comment: If you have few rows i don't believe it will make a difference. You will have to populate the tables with (fake) rows, as many as you expect them to contain in production level and then try. Of course performance is the 1st consideration. In case of ties in performance then choose readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Can more than two users be in a private chat?  If so, aggregation with `having` is probably the best approach:

```
select c.id 
from chats c inner join
     chat_user cu
     on cu.chat_id = c.id
where c.type = 'private' 
group by c.id
having count(*) filter (where cu.user_id in (1, 2)) = 2;
```

Of course, this works for only two users as well.  It just handles the more general case as well.

Comment: I don't believe that filtering after the aggregation on all the rows of the joined tables would perform better than using a normal WHERE clause which will limit dramatically the rows that need to be aggregated.